# Accessing a public method from a class inside a SurfaceListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, selectionchanged

I've created a WPF Solution as described on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff727730.aspx. This solution will provide me a continuous list using a `SurfaceListBox`. This is working ok, with no issues.

Now I'd like click on a image and move X pixels, in any direction.

So, I created the event `MainSurfaceListBox_OnSelectionChanged` and added that to `MainWindow.xaml`:

```
<Window x:Class="ContinuousList.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:s="http://schemas.microsoft.com/surface/2008"
        xmlns:l="clr-namespace:ContinuousList"
        Title="ContinuousList" Height="640" Width="800">
    <Grid>

        <s:SurfaceListBox Name="MainSurfaceListBox"
                          SelectionChanged="MainSurfaceListBox_OnSelectionChanged">
            <s:SurfaceListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image Source="{Binding}" Width="270"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </s:SurfaceListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <s:SurfaceListBox.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <s:SurfaceScrollViewer
                        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                        CanContentScroll="true">
                        <l:LoopPanelVertical IsItemsHost="True"/>
                    </s:SurfaceScrollViewer>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </s:SurfaceListBox.Template>
        </s:SurfaceListBox>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and inside `MainWindow.xaml.cs`

```
private void MainSurfaceListBox_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //trying to call a public method from LoopPanelVertical
}
```

Now, from `MainWindow.xaml.cs` I'm trying to run the method `LoopPanelVertical.LineUp()`. My issue is that I cannot find a way to access this method, or any public method from `LoopPanelVertical`.

```
namespace ContinuousList
{
    public class LoopPanelVertical : Panel, ISurfaceScrollInfo
    {
        ...
        public void LineUp()
        {
             ScrollContent(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Would please help me in understanding what it necessary to achieve that? Thanks!

Comment: The method I'm trying to access is public already. If you take a look at the code, you'll see that LineUp() is public.

Comment: By internal you meant it is inside the class I guess?

Comment: Yes, inside the class.

Comment: "So, I created a method MainSurfaceListBox_OnSelectionChanged" You meant event there?

Comment: *You'll be able to find all the code there*... nobody wants to see *all* of your code. You should make a [small, concise program that demonstrates your problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), rather than expecting us to do all of your work.

Comment: @Sheridan, is it better as a question now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found an answer for that using the child element:

```
 private void MainSurfaceListBox_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var listBox = sender as SurfaceListBox;
            if (listBox == null) return;
            var childElement = FindChild(listBox, i => i as LoopPanelVertical);
            childElement.LineUp();
        }

        static T FindChild<T>(DependencyObject obj, Func<DependencyObject, T> pred) where T : class
        {
            var childrenCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj);
            for (var i = 0; i < childrenCount; i++)
            {
                var dependencyObject = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, i);
                var foo = pred(dependencyObject);
                return foo ?? FindChild(dependencyObject, pred);
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to call a method of a (non static) class, you need to have a reference to an instance of that class. You can set the `Name` or `x:Name` property of your `LoopPanelVertical` class and then use that name to reference it:

```
<ControlTemplate>
    <s:SurfaceScrollViewer
        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
        CanContentScroll="true">
        <l:LoopPanelVertical x:Name="Panel" IsItemsHost="True"/>
    </s:SurfaceScrollViewer>
</ControlTemplate>
```

...

```
private void MainSurfaceListBox_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, 
    SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Panel.LineUp();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've updated the code with the name 'LoopPanel' as described: `<l:LoopPanelVertical x:Name="LoopPanel" IsItemsHost="True"/>` and inside the event, I've tried to reach the object, but I got the message "Cannot resolve the symbol 'LoopPanel'".